# Is there any way to change the CP navigation item for a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, navigation

I'm wondering if I can have another name for my Plugin CP navigation item?

Let's say my plugin is called "Company name Social Media" but I want the navigation item to just say "Social Media". Might be a bad example but I think you understand what I mean. Let's say I'll release a commercial Craft plugin w/ my company name in it, but I want the customer to be able to add the plugin for a client without my name visible (more then on the plugins page).

Also is there any way to add dropdown-like sub-navigation items to the CP navigation for a plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to change the name of the CP section, but it has become a common practice to allow each user to change the plugin-name on its setting page:

**main plugin file:**

```
function getName()
{
    return $this->getSettings()->name;
}

protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        'name' => array(AttributeType::String, 'default' => 'SuperPluginName')
    );
}
```

**settings template:**

```twig
{% import '_includes/forms' as forms %}

{{  forms.textField({
        first: true,
        label: "Plugin Name"|t,
        instructions: "How the plugin should be named in the CP"|t,
        id: 'name',
        name: 'name',
        value: settings.name,
        required: true
    }) 
}}
```

Comment: Any tips or info about adding dropdown items to the navigation item?

Comment: If you mean a dropdown like the one from the settings-link, that is only possible if you add it with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I use Victor In's "getName" function with a minor addition of a check of the type of value returned. I do this because without the value check, I get an error when I try to uninstall a plugin without confirming the value is a string.

Here's my version of the function:

```
function getName() {
    $name = $this->getSettings()->name;
    if (is_string($name) ){
        return $name;
    } else {
        return Craft::t( 'My Default Plugin Name Here' );
    }
}
```